# ¿Cuándo es necesario modificar HashCode para modificar Equals?

Tags: java

Estoy estudiando la modificación de Equals sin modificar Hashcode.

```
public class Phone {
    private final int areaCode ;
    private final int number ;

    public Phone(int ac, int n) {
        areaCode = ac ;
        number=n ;
    }

    @Override public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if(o==this)return true ;
        if( !(o instanceof Phone)) return false ;
        Phone pn = (Phone)o ;
        return areaCode==pn.areaCode && number==pn.number ;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Phone, String> m = new HashMap<Phone, String>() ;
        m.put(new Phone(0033, 123456), "Cornaz") ;

        System.out.println(m.get(new Phone(0033, 123456))) ;
    }
}
```

devuelve `null`. Parece que la razón es que se utilizan dos instancias de Phone (agregar y luego buscar): el código hash del objeto es diferente: no en la misma bolsa.

Pero cuando no lo modifico hay tambien `null`

```
public class Phone {
    private final int areaCode ;
    private final int number ;

    public Phone(int ac, int n) {
        areaCode = ac ;
        number=n ;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Phone, String> m = new HashMap<Phone, String>() ;
        m.put(new Phone(0033, 123456), "Cornaz") ;

        System.out.println(m.get(new Phone(0033, 123456))) ;
    }
}
```

Por consequencia :

1. **¿Cuándo es necesario modificar HashCode para modificar Equals?**
2. **¿Qué se necesita para tener un buen hascode?**

Answer (score 1):

Voy a intentar ayudarte en algo pero antes de nada ¿cual es la diferencia entre tus dos métodos main? Yo los veo completamente iguales.

Si usas un objeto como clave en el map y cada vez que insertas algo creas un nuevo objeto, obviamente cada objeto tendrá un hashcode diferente y si buscas con un "new Phone(...)" no vas a encontrar nada.

Las cosas funcionan mas o menos así - el map busca por el hashcode de la clave. En el caso el método equals del objeto clave no importa. Lo que importa es el hash. Cada vez que creas un objeto tendrás un hashcode diferente porque Object te devuelve algo como una representación hexadecimal de la dirección de memoria donde se ubica el objeto. Por lo tanto no puedes buscar creando un nuevo objeto y esperar que te devuelva algo aunque a simple vista el objeto que metiste y el que creas sean iguales.

Hasta aquí bien. Ahora sobre el hashcode.

Cada vez que invocas hashcode sobre el mismo objeto debe devolver el mismo valor (el mismo objeto, nada de new!!!) y no proporciona información sobre la comparación con equals.

Si dos objetos son iguales según equals deben devolver el mismo hashcode (aquí es donde fallas en tu implementación de Phone).

No es obligatorio si dos objetos no son iguales según equals devuelvan diferentes hascodes (no es un valor único).

En tu caso para cumplir con el contrato de hashcode, pues lo debes implementar. Esto te debe servir:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result;
    result = (int) (areaCode ^ (areaCode>>> 32));
    result = 31 * result + (int) (number^ (number>>> 32));
    return result;
}
```

A ver si puedo responder a tus preguntas.

1. ¿Cuándo es necesario modificar HashCode para modificar Equals?

Básicamente si sobreescribes uno debes hacerlo con el otro pero no del todo. Necesitas equals para ordenación, a lo mejor no necesitas hashCode. Pero si sobreescribes hashCode debes sobreescribir equals porque dos objetos iguales deben devolver el mismo hashcode.

2. ¿Qué se necesita para tener un buen hascode?

Básicamente que devuelva un valor cuanto más único mejor.

Espero haberte ayudado